# EPERM: operation not permitted, stat 'C:\$Recycle.Bin\desktop.ini'

Tags: npm, vite

trying to build a react app with vite(npm run build) but this appears.
cleaned cashe and reinstalled npm a couple times with vs code closedbut still doesnt work. tried using the command as administator in the terminal but still the error appears and some random files from the C: appeared in the outDir folder like bootmgr (not the real one, it onlt appeard in vs code and deleting it didnt do anything and the real bootmgr is still in C:)

EPERM: operation not permitted, stat 'C:$Recycle.Bin\desktop.ini'
error during build:
Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, stat 'C:$Recycle.Bin\desktop.ini'
at Object.statSync (node:fs:1551:3)
at copyDir (C:\Users\HP\Desktop\XalinPaintWeb\XalinPaint\node_modules\vite\dist\node\chunks\dep-59dc6e00.js:2553:34)
at copyDir (C:\Users\HP\Desktop\XalinPaintWeb\XalinPaint\node_modules\vite\dist\node\chunks\dep-59dc6e00.js:2555:13)
at prepareOutDir (C:\Users\HP\Desktop\XalinPaintWeb\XalinPaint\node_modules\vite\dist\node\chunks\dep-59dc6e00.js:41439:9)
at doBuild (C:\Users\HP\Desktop\XalinPaintWeb\XalinPaint\node_modules\vite\dist\node\chunks\dep-59dc6e00.js:41408:13)
at async build (C:\Users\HP\Desktop\XalinPaintWeb\XalinPaint\node_modules\vite\dist\node\chunks\dep-59dc6e00.js:41244:16)
at async CAC. (C:\Users\HP\Desktop\XalinPaintWeb\XalinPaint\node_modules\vite\dist\node\cli.js:738:9)

Answer (score 0):

the value in the public dir in the vite config was "/src" and it tried to get the value not from the relative location like location/src but C:/src

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).